# How can I subscribe pending transaction which are filtered by 'to' address?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, pending-transactions, filters

I tried to subscribe pending transactions by using ethers.js and the code is below.

subscription = provider.on("pending", (txHash) => {
if (!onRunning) {
processTx(txHash);
}
});

But when I run this code, it produces plenty amount of call to processTx(async function) and  the function does not be completed. It produces the err msg below.
[image]

so How can I fix this?
I think there are two ways to solve this problem.
-first, reduce call amount to processTx
I think I can use Alchemy SDK to get filtered transaction that reduces call amount to processTx. and any other way?
-second, complete these plenty amount of call to processTx.